# how can I overload this data access layer method with a sql connection object

Tags: c#, ado.net, data-access-layer, bll

Both Services use the AddChildrenUnit method of the IUnitDataProvider.

The TemplateService has to pass this method an already open connection object because the CreateTemplate method must run in a transaction for AddTemplate and "Create the root unit node".

The UnitService does not pass a connection object to the AddChildrenUnit method therefore the code does not compile !!!

My question is now: I can not change the AddChildrenUnit method and remove the sqlconnection parameter else the AddChildrenUnit in the CreateTemplate method will not compile anymore.

So what can I do now? The only thing I can think of is an overloaded version of the AddChildrenUnit one time with a SqlConnection parameter and one method without this parameter.

Thats cumbersome...

Do you know a better solution?

**TemplateService**:

```
public void CreateTemplate(Template template)
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope()) 
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        _templateDataProvider.AddTemplate(template,connection);
        Unit rootUnit = new Unit{ TemplateId = template.TemplateId, ParentId = null, Name = "Root" };
        _unitDataProvider.AddChildrenUnit(rootUnit,connection);

        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

**UnitService**:

```
public void AddChildrenUnit(Unit unit)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        IEnumerable<Unit> childrenUnits = _unitDataProvider.GetChildrenUnits(unit.UnitId); // Selected ParentId
        int hierarchyIndexOfSelectedUnitId = childrenUnits.Select(u => u.HierarchyIndex).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max(c => c);
        int hierarchyIndexOfNewChild = hierarchyIndexOfSelectedUnitId + 1;
        unit.HierarchyIndex = hierarchyIndexOfNewChild;

        _unitDataProvider.AddChildrenUnit(unit);
    }
}
```

**UNITDATAPROVIDER**:

```
/// <summary>
///  INSERT new child at the end of the children which is the highest HierarchyIndex 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="unit"></param>
public void AddChildrenUnit(Unit unit) // 10 ms
{
    using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UNIT (Name,TemplateId,ParentId,CreatedAt,HierarchyIndex) VALUES (@Name,@TemplateId,@ParentId,@CreatedAt,@HierarchyIndex);Select Scope_Identity();",con))
    {
        con.Open();

        // INSERT new child at the end of the children which is the highest HierarchyIndex                
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HierarchyIndex", unit.HierarchyIndex); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TemplateId", unit.TemplateId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", unit.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = unit.CreatedAt; 

        unit.UnitId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        trans.Complete();
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public void AddChildrenUnit(Unit unit) // 10 ms
{
    AddChilrenUnit(unit, new SqlConnection(_connectionString));
}

public void AddChildrenUnit(Unit unit, SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
    using (connection))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UNIT (Name,TemplateId,ParentId,CreatedAt,HierarchyIndex) VALUES (@Name,@TemplateId,@ParentId,@CreatedAt,@HierarchyIndex);Select Scope_Identity();",con))
    {
        con.Open();

        // INSERT new child at the end of the children which is the highest HierarchyIndex                
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HierarchyIndex", unit.HierarchyIndex); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TemplateId", unit.TemplateId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", unit.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = unit.CreatedAt; 

        unit.UnitId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        trans.Complete();
    }             

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will do.

```
public interface IUnitDataProvider
{
    void AddChildrenUnit(Unit unit, string connectionString);
}


public class UnitService:IUnitDataProvider
{
    //Implement AddChildrenUnit the way want
    //pass the connection string but u dont use it
}

public interface UnitDataProvider:IUnitDataProvider
{
    //Implement AddChildrenUnit the way want
}
```

public class templateClass
  {

```
private IUnitDataProvider _unitDataProvider;

public templateClass(IUnitDataProvider provider)
{
        _unitDataProvider=provider
}

public void CreateTemplate(Template template)
{
    //pre -addUnit code here

   _unitDataProvider.AddChildrenUnit(unit, connectionstring);

    //Post -addUnit code here

}
```

}

so based on the your usage you pass the right concrete implementation to the constructor of the TemplateClass  ( i named it TemplateClass , I don't know what you called it)